# The Inerrant Word of God, (ref Mark:16:9-20)

Tags: contradiction, textual-criticism, mark

I don't doubt that the Bible is the inspired and inerrant Word of God, because I believe that God is big enough to ensure the accurate representation of Himself and His creation's relationship to Him. However, the Bible's notation re: Mark 16:9-20 highlights a reasonable point of skepticism brought up by both believer and unbeliever.

If these verses are noted as not having been included in earlier manuscripts, how implausible is it that other things (whether factual or false) were added or removed as manuscripts exchanged hands?

I guess my real questions are:

(1) Where in the Bible does it encourage us to trust the canonized compilation books as the inerrant Word of God? What references do you use? 
(2)How do I consider and respond to the seemingly fair observation that our modern day Bible has undergone man-made manipulation over the years (including the many versions of the Bible that is offered today)?

Comment: Welcome to BH.SE! Please [take the tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a feel for how the site operates. Firstly, this site is not for the defense of the Bible as the inerrant word of God. It's purpose is to determine as best as is possible the intended "original" meaning of a text. However, for your question to a good question at a site that might be interested in arguments for/against inerrancy, I would suggest you explain what you understand by inerrancy, and then how the inclusion or exclusion of Mark 16:9-20 impacts that understanding.

Comment: Hi there, I don't question the truth of God's own Word. My question was in regards to how to respond to valid observations re: the possible influence of human fallibility *and* immorality when it comes to what is actually included in the Bible, including the selection of books, as well as the in the growing number of contemporary translations which even Christians argue about in regards to accuracy. I thought this an appropriate place to get insight from other believers who'd honestly asked the question themselves and could give an answer from their own research. Okay, take care.

Comment: If you know of other communities where such a question would be more appropriate, and where thoughtful, researched and respectful discussion is the norm, please share.

Comment: This site is not exclusive to "believers", and as such you are unlikely to get the feedback you want. In regard to believers, you will likely find that the fundamental principles that God wants to convey by means of the text of scripture are unimpeded by human intervention -- the Spirit that inspired the writers of the text is the same Spirit that moves those who read and believe, regardless of the language in which those principles are couched.

Answer (score 1):

Inerrant means to be infallible.  The Bible is the record of God's word, which is truth.  It is also the Holy Spirit's record of the actions of men and women throughout time, and also of the words and actions of the Adversary (Satan).  We recognize that when God speaks His words are truth and His commandments are to be obeyed.

At the same time, we recognize that the Holy Spirit accurately recorded the events in the record of people and of the Adversary, while acknowledging that the words spoken by men are those of fallible men which may or may not have been true words.  The Spirit accurately recorded what they said and did.

We also recognize that the words and actions accurately recorded by the Holy Spirit of the Adversary are those of a liar (John 8:44).  So, we have the record of what the Adversary said and did, while knowing that his statements are not to be relied upon as truth.  A liar speaks lies.

The record is infallible because it was recorded by the Holy Spirit. God and His prophets spoke truth to the people.  We still must identify the speaker to distinguish God's true words from those of fallible men who were not prophets of God, or from those of the lying Adversary.

2 Pet. 1:20-21,

> "20 knowing this first, that no prophecy of Scripture is of any private interpretation, 21 for prophecy never came by the will of man, but holy men of God spoke as they were moved by the Holy Spirit."  (NKJV)

Think of the men that were moved to write by the Holy Spirit as being God's secretaries.

Our faith and trust in God and His word grows the more that we study it.  We can believe that He has provided us with His word even through all of the thousands of years that mankind has tried to destroy it.

We have the assurance from within His word.

Psa. 119:160,

> "Thy word is true from the beginning: and every one of thy righteous judgments endureth for ever."  (KJV)

Matt. 22:16,

> "And they sent out unto him their disciples with the Herodians, saying, Master, we know that thou art true, and teachest the way of God in truth, neither carest thou for any man: for thou regardest not the person of men."  (KJV)

Mark 12:14,

> "And when they were come, they say unto him, Master, we know that thou art true, and carest for no man: for thou regardest not the person of men, but teachest the way of God in truth: Is it lawful to give tribute to Caesar, or not?"  (KJV)

John 8:26,

> :I have many things to say and to judge of you: but he that sent me is true; and I speak to the world those things which I have heard of him." (KJV)

John 19:35,

> "And he that saw it bare record, and his record is true: and he knoweth that he saith true, that ye might believe."  (KJV)

John 21:24,

> "This is the disciple which testifieth of these things, and wrote these things: and we know that his testimony is true." (KJV)

See also 2 Cor. 1:17-24; 3 John 1:12; Rev. 15:3, 19:9, 21:5, 22:6.

We also have the assurances of many scholars.  Apologetics Press (Apologeticspress.org) has many articles on the inspiration of the Bible.

Excerpt from Dave Miller's *3 Good Reasons to Believe The Bible Has Not Been Corrupted:*

> "Many are those who insist that the Bible has been corrupted over time, that we do not really know which verses belong in the Bible, and that translation errors are so plentiful that we do not have the original message. Yet these allegations have been confronted and refuted time and time again. Apart from the Old Testament (which has been fully verified), a myriad of books over the years have masterfully demonstrated the integrity of the New Testament text, including such volumes as J.W. McGarvey’s Evidences of Christianity, Kurt and Barbara Aland’s The Text of the New Testament, F.F. Bruce’s The Canon of Scripture, Bruce Metzger’s The Text of the New Testament, F.H.A. Scrivener’s A Plain Introduction to the Criticism of the New Testament, Sir Frederic Kenyon’s Our Bible and the Ancient Manuscripts, Benjamin Warfield’s An Introduction to the Textual Criticism of the New Testament, and many others. Those who cast aspersions upon the integrity of the biblical text manifest either abysmal, inexcusable ignorance of the long established facts of the matter or deliberate bias. If the reader desires the truth regarding the authenticity and integrity of the Bible, the evidence is available—if the individual is willing to spend the time and effort to weigh that evidence and arrive at the proper conclusion (1 Thessalonians 5:21; 1 John 4:1). Do we have the message that the original authors penned? The fact is that the books of the New Testament are the most extensively verified books of ancient history. The facts completely undermine and discredit any attack on the integrity and transmission of the Bible."  Source: [here](http://apologeticspress.org/APContent.aspx?category=13&article=5196).

He discusses 1) The New Testament Greek text has been authenticated; 2) The translation process works; and 3) The history of the English translation demonstrates preservation.

We also know that the miracles that Christ and the disciples / apostles performed were the proof offered to the people that their words were true and were authorized by our Father in heaven.

Acts 1:3,

> "To whom also he shewed himself alive after his passion by many infallible proofs, being seen of them forty days, and speaking of the things pertaining to the kingdom of God:"  (KJV)

Acts 2:22,

> "Ye men of Israel, hear these words; Jesus of Nazareth, **a man approved of God among you by miracles and wonders and signs**, which God did by him in the midst of you, as ye yourselves also know:"  (KJV; bold emphasis mine.)

See also Acts 6:8, 8:6, 8:13, 15;12, 19:11; 1 Cor. 12:28; Heb 2:4.

The miracles which Christ worked, and those by the Spirit which was poured forth upon those baptized into Christ confirmed the word of God.  The miracles were always for the purpose of proving that what had been said was authorized by God.

The controversy over the inclusion or exclusion of Mark 16:9-20 has been discussed by many, and have proponents on both sides.  You may find the article *Is Mark 16:9-20 Insprired?* also at Apologetics Press of interest. It investigates the pros and cons of both positions, and concludes:

> "For the unbiased observer, this matter is settled: the strongest piece of internal evidence mustered against the genuineness of Mark 16:9-20 is no evidence at all. The two strongest arguments offered to discredit the inspiration of these verses as the production of Mark are seen to be lacking in substance and legitimacy. The reader of the New Testament may be confidently assured that these verses are original—written by the Holy Spirit through the hand of Mark as part of his original gospel account."  Source: [here](http://apologeticspress.org/APContent.aspx?category=13&article=704&topic=103).

See also *3 Good Reasons to Believe the Bible is From God*, by Eric Lyons and Kyle Butt at Apologetics Press [here](http://apologeticspress.org/APContent.aspx?category=13&article=5089); and *Biblical Inerrancy* by Dave Miller, and Eric Lyons [here](http://apologeticspress.org/APContent.aspx?category=13&article=472).

Young's Literal Translation is a word for word translation from the Hebrew and Greek texts.  It is a little choppy to read alone, but a good companion to study with the KJV, or ASV, etc.

Comment: Gina, you haven't made it clear what "inerrant" means in regard to the Bible, nor how Mark 16:9-20 is/isn't connected with that idea.

Comment: Hi Gina, I appreciate your taking the time to cite many resources. I was seeking help getting a clear, concise response that displays genuine consideration of textual and historical research and any inconvenient inconsistencies found. I'm sure I'll be referencing some your resources as I continue to look into the canonization process, the conflict of cultural mindsets vs. Jesus' example, and into conflicts over things such as "Junia". It'd be nice to have honest, humble, researched responses. But ultimately, I rest in the knowledge that the Lord's will simply transcends human deficiencies.

Comment: QElbert.. I hope the answer was of some help.